# jQuery: wrong reference to objects when trying to bind event

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, events, bind

Ok, had such problem ...
I'm trying to reduce amount of code, required to validate fields.
In this case I've created array with ids of elements which I wanted to bind events to.
Like this:

```
var fields = new Array('#edit-field-first-name', '#edit-field-last-name', '#edit-field-mobile');
```

Then I'm binding events in a loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
  if($('#user-profile-form ' + fields[i]).length > 0){
    var $obj = $('#user-profile-form ' + fields[i]);
    $obj.bind({
      blur :  function(){
                  if(!reg_chars.test($obj.val())){
                      $obj.css('border','1px solid #A14')
                          .parent().children('div.description').css('color', '#A14');
                  }else{
                      $obj.css('border-style','solid').css('border-color','#C5C3C3 #EDEDED #EDEDED #C5C3C3').css('border-width','1px')
                         .parent().children('div.description').css('color', '#333');
                  };
              }
    })
  }
}
```

And now strange things happen.
It's triggering "blur" event properly. But it's always referencing to last element in array. Looks like it's always using the same object and just overwriting it every loop iteration.

So need help ... What can be a solution?

Comment: what do you mean that it's "triggering the blur event properly" if it's always only picking the last element?

Comment: It is normal because the last value you gave to obj is the last value of the table. So when you use it you retrieve the last value affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem within context ($obj) assignment at bind function. Try to change to

```
    for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
      if($('#user-profile-form ' + fields[i]).length > 0){
        var $obj = $('#user-profile-form ' + fields[i]);
        $obj.bind({
          blur :  function(){
                      var $input = $(this);                      

                      if(!reg_chars.test($input.val())){
                          $input.css('border','1px solid #A14')
                              .parent().children('div.description').css('color', '#A14');
                      }else{
                          $input.css('border-style','solid').css('border-color','#C5C3C3 #EDEDED #EDEDED #C5C3C3').css('border-width','1px')
                             .parent().children('div.description').css('color', '#333');
                      };
                  }
        })
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, already sorted out ... :) My problem is that I need to have more sleep ... :)))))

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend spending the time to go through John Resig's tutorial [Learning Advanced Javascript](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/).  It will help you solve this problem and will also give you a deeper understanding of Javascript.